# Get the rows matching min value given by sub query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a `NAMES` table with columns `id` and `name`.

Query is to fetch the results based on the letter that has least number of words ending by itself.

Ex: henry, harry, john, fredrick are the names i have in my table. n and k are the letters that have only 1 word with them as end letters.

This is what I have done so far..

```
select substr(name, -1, 1) as character, 
       count(*) as wordscount
  from names              
 group by substr(name, -1, 1)
 order by count(*);
```

This fetches me results as below

```
 character   wordscount
----------- ------------
 n           1
 k           1
 y           2
```

My query should fetch results like

```
 character   wordscount
----------- ------------
 n           1
 k           1
```

I don't want to use `rownum = 1` because there may be multiple letters with same least number of words.

```
select *
  from (select substr(name, -1, 1) as character,
               count(*) as wordsCount
          from names              
         group by substr(name, -1, 1)
         order by count(*))
where rownum = 1;
```

I do not want to use above query because this will omit `k  1` from my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for having?

```
select substr(name, -1, 1) as character, count(*) as wordscount from names              
group by substr(name, -1, 1) having count(*)= (  
    select min(count(*)) from   names              
     group by substr(name, -1, 1)
 )
```

Or without having with additional wrapper:

```
select * from (
select substr(name, -1, 1) as character, count(*) as wordscount from names              
group by substr(name, -1, 1) ) A  where wordscount = (  
    select min(count(*)) from   names              
     group by substr(name, -1, 1)
 )
```

Comment: This does exactly what i need. But is there any alternative to  "having"

Comment: I cannot upvote coz of my low reputation. Thanks a lot for your help